# Python program erroring out with "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a python object"

Tags: python, recursion

I have a python program that I am currently working on which is working pretty well except for the fact that I am running into "recursion depth" issues and I am not sure how to rework my program to avoid this.

my program is basically something like this in a nutshell:

```
def foo()
    x = 0 # 

    while x != 1:
        x = (mydll.InPortB(base+1)) & 1 # this is a hardware input like a push button(on or off)
        time.sleep(0.5)

     bar = ser.readline() # input from serial source
     if len(bar) != 10:
         foo()
     ''' it continues checking "bar" using some more if statement. Finally when the
         logic is satisfied the program outputs something but still restarts foo() as
         I need the program to run endlessly but I am not sure how to fix the recursive
         nature of the program'''
      if bar = 1234567890:
          print "yay you win"
          foo()
#start
foo()
```

Ultimately my program works as it is but eventually will crash out with the recursion limit error so not ideal as I need this program to run endlessly but being a total newb to programming I am unsure how to fix it. I did try to split my program into two or three separate function rather than just the one but it was still exhibiting the recursion issue.

Thanks for any input. If anyone needs more code I can post it but thought the small piece should be sufficient to see where I am going. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could make the arming while loop more concise this way: `while not (mydll.InPortB(base+1)) & 1: time.sleep(0.5)`

Comment: Am I misreading that, or shouldn't that `while` block run infinitely if entered?

Comment: Thanks sr2222. That helped cleanup my code a little. I had tried a few iterations and couldn't get it to work right but your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @Daenyth, if you are referring to my original code then "arming" was a misprint, it should have been X instead. Copy/paste issue. :-0 If you were referring to sr2222's suggestion, it worked out perfectly.

Comment: @ouldsmobile: Your original code. You should update the question with the correct code.

Comment: @Daenyth thanks for pointing out the error, it has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this since it repeatedly calls the function at the same recursion level:

```
def foo()
    x = 0 # 
    while arming != 1:
        x = (mydll.InPortB(base+1)) & 1 # this is a hardware input like a push button(on or off)
        time.sleep(0.5)

     bar = ser.readline() # input from serial source
     if len(bar) != 10:

     ''' it continues checking "bar" using some more if statement. Finally when the
         logic is satisfied the program outputs something but still restarts foo() as
         I need the program to run endlessly but I am not sure how to fix the recursive
         nature of the program'''
      if bar = 1234567890:
          print "yay you win"

#start
while 1:
    foo()
```

Comment: If I infer his logic correctly, I think he may need to pull the `if len(bar) != 10:` block out and put it in a while loop inside `while True:` with the print statement coming after the len check on bar in the main body of code.

Comment: This is the route I chose to go though I am pretty sure the other answers would have worked as well. I had to rejig a couple of my IF statements but in the end it seems like this is working well. I am going to let it run overnight to see if it runs without exiting. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Inside of foo just use a loop such as:

```
while True:

    x = 0 # 
    while arming != 1:
        x = (mydll.InPortB(base+1)) & 1 # this is a hardware input like a push button(on or off)
        time.sleep(0.5)

     bar = ser.readline() # input from serial source
     if len(bar) != 10:
         # do whatever you want but don't call foo
```

You don't need to call foo recursively for the program to keep running. The while True will take care of that.